# Can i export a wordpress site to html?

Tags: html, wordpress, blogger

I want to export a wordpress site with themes and images to html format like we can do in blogspot. Is there a plugin or a tool for the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably http://www.HTTrack.com/ is the right tool for you:
It is an easy-to-use offline browser utility and allows you to download websites "to a local directory, building recursively all directories, getting HTML, images, and other files from the server to your computer".

Answer (score 2):

The [WP Static HTML Output](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/static-html-output-plugin/) plugin will do this.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain? As far as I can tell, this is precisely what was asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a [website scraper](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=website%20scraper#sclient=psy&hl=en&safe=off&biw=1280&bih=709&source=hp&q=website%20scraping%20software&pbx=1&oq=website%20scraping%20software&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=4609l6971l0l7171l14l8l0l0l0l0l199l199l0.1l1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=68b2c9f6e06f422c) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use wget. It has a lot of flexibility, but is all done with one easy command. If you're on windows you'll probably have to install it first.